# What is the name of this topology on the set of branches in a tree?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory, terminology, order-theory

In combinatorial set theory/set-theoretic topology, a *tree* is a partially ordered set $(T, <)$ s.t. for all $x$, the downset $\{ y \in T: y < x\}$ is wellordered (the order type of this set is called the *height* of $x$).  A *branch* of $T$ is a maximal chain in $T$.  I write $[T]$ for the set of branches of $T$.  I think of $[T]$ as a topological space whose clopen basis is $\{[[x]] : x \in T\}$, where $[[x]]$ is the set of branches containing $x$.

If the height of each node in $T$ is finite, the topology of $[T]$ coincides with the product topology.  What is the topology of $[T]$ called if each node possibly has infinite height, and what is a good source on this topological space?  Obvious names like *tree topology* or *branch space* have been taken for something else.  Tree topology is a topology on $T$ itself.  A branch space's underlying set is of the form $[T]$, but its topology depend on additional data about $T$.

Comment: [This paper](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/giorgio/papers/ast2014.pdf) calls something equivalent the _bounded topology_. It's actually the topology on the generalized Baire space $\kappa^\kappa$, but I think you can construe every tree as a subtree of some such space. Nevertheless, it seems that this term is also used in algebraic topology and I don't know if the two concepts are related.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thank you.  Yes, it does seem that some set theorists call the topology bounded topology.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space of branches with this topology has been called simply the *branch space* of the tree. This is the term used, for instance, by Luther Bush Fuller in [*Trees and proto-metrizable spaces*](http://msp.org/pjm/1983/104-1/pjm-v104-n1-p06-s.pdf) [PDF] and by Yuan-Qing Qiao and Frank Tall in [*Perfectly normal non-metrizable non-Archimedean spaces are generalized Souslin lines*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-12/S0002-9939-03-06966-1/S0002-9939-03-06966-1.pdf) [PDF]. Gary Gruenhage used the same term in his chapter *Generalized Metric Spaces* in the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, though he enclosed it in scare quotes. However, Stevo Todorčević uses the same term for the space of branches with a somewhat different topology in his chapter *Trees and linearly ordered sets* in the same handbook, and Hal Bennett, Dave Lutzer, and Mary Ellen Rudin also use it for this topology in [*Lines, Trees, and Branch Spaces*](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~habennet/hal_vita/TreesLinesBranchSpaces.pdf) [PDF].

The term *bounded topology* that **Pedro Sánchez Terraf** found also appears in [*Souslin quasi-orders and definable cardinality*](http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/andretta/preprints/AM.pdf) [PDF], by Alessandro Andretta and Luca Motto Ros, [*Questions on Generalized Baire Spaces*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fce6/daf0ae84549f18c499e4ee9bbf64a0c377f1.pdf) [PDF], by Yurii Khomskii, Giorgio Laguzzi, Benedikt Löwe, and Ilya Sharankou, and [*The Hurewicz dichotomy for generalized Baire spaces*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03364.pdf) [PDF], by Philipp Lücke, Luca Motto Ros, and Philipp Schlicht, among other places.

Comment: +1 I'll explicitly misuse the comment section to thank you for many useful references!

Comment: @Pedro: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Any tree can be embedded in some full $\kappa$-ary tree $\kappa^{<\kappa}$, and its set of branches will be a subset of the *generalized Baire space* $\kappa^\kappa$. The usual topology on $\kappa^\kappa$, called **bounded topology** in [this paper](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/giorgio/papers/ast2014.pdf), has a base of the form 
$$
[s] := \{f \in \kappa^\kappa : f \restriction |s| = s\}
$$
where $s\in\kappa^{<\kappa}$. These correspond to your sets $[[s]]$ via the natural embedding $T\hookrightarrow \kappa^{<\kappa}$.

It seems that that this term is also used in algebraic topology but I doubt the two concepts are related.